# How to prevent apache from reducing double slashes with single slash in a URL path?

Tags: php, apache, url, path

Apache has a very annoying tendancy to replace double slashes in the URL with a single.

Example:

Request URL: `http://example.com/myscript.php/foo//bar`

When I look at the

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
```

var, the path info will show up as:

```
foo/bar
```

instead of

```
foo//bar
```

Does anyone know of a fix for this? I believe this is ingrained somewhere in apache's functionality... I don't know if there's some kind of an apache flag that can be tweaked to disable this behavior.

Comment: why do you want to keep double slashes ? ... Also I'm pretty sure it's the browser that fixes it since its an invalid url...

Comment: @Erik Not the browser. The URL is not invalid. The double slash in this instance is part of the _additional path information_ (PATH_INFO) - the part of the URL that trails an existing (valid) URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of RFC standard for resolve URIs so you can't change that.

Even probably your browser normalize the URI before send the request to the remote server.

Comment: Eh, I was afraid the answer would be something like that... oh well. Annoying.

Comment: You can escape the character / and replace it with the ASCII value, see urlencode()

Answer (score 1):

> `http://example.com/myscript.php/foo//bar`

The `/foo//bar` is the *additional path information* that follows an actual filename. Whilst Apache does reduce the multiple slashes in the PATH_INFO server variable (which is passed through to the corresponding PHP superglobal), the original URL (with multiple slashes) is still available in the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] variable.

So, instead of accessing the path info via the `PATH_INFO` variable, you could do something like the following instead:

```
$pathInfo = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

This simply removes the SCRIPT_NAME from PHP_SELF, leaving the *path-info* (if any). You could use REQUEST_URI instead of PHP_SELF, but this includes the query string, so you would need to check for this.

So, given the above request, where `SCRIPT_NAME` is "/myscript.php" and `PHP_SELF` is "/myscript.php/foo//bar", then the resulting `$pathInfo` is "/foo//bar".

Answer (score 0):

nginx has a merge_slashes directive that allows slashes to be merged to match a location and it defaults to off, meaning it doesn't merge by default. If the merging behavior is specified in the RFC, it's certainly not followed by nginx.